# ClassNotFoundError while running AspectJ android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, aspectj, monkey

I have an Android Project, I converted the same into AspectJ project for MonkeyTool but when we run this into emulator or device it returns ClassNotFoundError. I am not able to figure out this problem because the same project is running safely on every device as an Android Project. Please find below the LogCat for better understanding:

**LogCat:**

```
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.handygo.rockasap.RockstandApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.handygo.rockasap.RockstandApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.handygo.rockasap-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.handygo.rockasap-1, /system/lib]]
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.handygo.rockasap.RockstandApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.handygo.rockasap-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.handygo.rockasap-1, /system/lib]]
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
02-04 02:21:38.108: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
```

**My Manifest file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.comp.name"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="57"
    android:versionName="4.1.9" >

    <!-- android:maxSdkVersion="17" max version create problem in Reader -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>


    <permission
        android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <!-- Version check the WIFI and Location permission -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".RockstandApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <service android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.utils.GCMIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".utils.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.handygo.rockasap" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".utils.NetworkCheckReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- <service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService" />   
        <receiver
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.services.ReferralReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".utils.BookReaderEventsReciever"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.utils.BookReaderEvents" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".utils.BootCompleteReciever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".screens.RBReader"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:label="Rockstand"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".error.BugReportActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="FBReader crash"
            android:process=":crash"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.NewspapersActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.FixBooksDirectoryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":crash"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.CRASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="CachedCharStorageException" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":crash"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.CRASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="ExceptionInInitializerError" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.api.ApiService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.API" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
           <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AuthenticationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.BuyBooksActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AddCatalogMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AddCustomCatalogActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AuthorizationMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.TopupMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkBookInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.ListenerCallback"
            android:process=":networkLibrary" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.network.SIGNIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".screens.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.UpdatingScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".menu.RASAPActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.HomeActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.BookShelfActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".browser.CustomWebBrowserActivity"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.WebPayUActivity"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />
        <activity
            android:name=".bookshelf.IneractiveBook"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.NotificationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".bookshelf.MyVideo_Palyer"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.Panel" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.OutlineActivity"
            android:label="@string/outline_title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <!-- NATIVE LOGIN -->


        <!-- The authenticator service -->
        <service
            android:name=".services.AuthenticationService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".screens.AuthenticatorActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.RegistrationActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.BookMagazineListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.PurchaseHistoryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".download.DownloadMngrListActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.BookDetailActivityNew"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.FBReaderCLass"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:label="Rockstand"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.FinishActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.ShareOnWebActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:process=":networkLibrary" />
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.TakeATour"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.OperatorPackageListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.BookDetailsMoreReviews"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".utils.GcmAlert"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.SmsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <service android:name=".services.RockstandService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".screens.SubscriptionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.ChangePassworddActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.ScreenShotsActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.RockstandUserProfileActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.MoreActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.SearchActivityNew"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_activity_new"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Provider Added by mithilesh -->
        <provider
            android:name=".DataProvider"
            android:authorities="com.handygo.rockasap.DataProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true" >
        </provider>

         <!-- Provider Added by mithilesh -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
                  android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please suggest any solution regarding the same.

Answer (score -2):

`"com.handygo.rockasap.RockstandApplication"`, this class is exists in project but not have an entry of Android Manifest so please give Entry and try... like

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.RockstandApplication"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_activity_new"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Its an application class name not an activity.....please read carefully, so we can't make entry this as Activity, its already mentioned in the name of application tag in manifest.